# Image of first quadrant under $f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis

help with this excercise

Find the image of region $$K=\{z=x+iy:x>0,y>0\}$$ under the function $f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$

---

$$w=\frac{z-i}{z+i}=\frac{(x^2+y^2-1)+((y-1)x-(y+1)x)i}{x^2+(y+1)^2}$$

I have.

$$u(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2+(y+1)^2}, v(x,y)=\frac{(y-1)x-(y+1)x)}{x^2+(y+1)^2}.$$

ok?

then?

Comment: You're doing this the wrong way round. Rearrange to get $z$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ then apply the conditions on $z$