# Find the image of region $K=\{z\in C:0<\arg z<\pi/4\}$ under the function $f(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Help with this excercise.

Find the image of region $$K=\{z\in C:0<\arg z<\pi/4\}$$

under the function $f(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}$

Comment: Dear NumberYob, yesterday you asked an almost identical question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251032/image-of-first-quadrant-under-fz-fracz-izi/. I tried to give a hint, but it appears that it didn't address your concerns. Could you please let us know what you already know about Mobius transformations / conformal transformations, and what you would like further clarification about? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT...Rearrange so you have $$z=\frac{w}{w-1}$$

Then $$0<\arg\left(\frac{w}{w-1}\right)<\frac{\pi}{4}$$

can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* 
$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{z-1} = 1+\frac{1}{z-1}
$$
and so $f$ is the conjugation of inversion by a translation. Focus on the inversion.