# Image of $0<\arg(z)<\pi/4$ under the mapping $ w=\frac{z}{z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of the domain $D=\{z\in C:0<\arg z<\pi/4\}$ under the mapping $ w=\frac{z}{z-1}$

I have tried to map the 2 border lines $y=0$ and $y=x$ where $x>0$ and $y>0$ but I'm struggling with the latter one.

Can anyone help me with this or do you have a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you know that Möbius transformations: 1) map lines to circles or lines, 2) are uniquely determined by their image at three distinct points?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252701/find-the-image-of-region-k-z-in-c0-arg-z-pi-4-under-the-function-fz?rq=1

Comment: @MartinR yes I do. How can I apply this to the problem? I don't really know a general way of doing these sorts of problems.

Comment: @Katie: What are the images of $0, i, \infty$ under the mapping? What does that mean for the image of the ray $\arg z = \pi/4$?

Comment: @MartinR They are 0, 1/2 - 1/2i, 1 respectively. I drew a circle passing through images of 3 points of the ray $\arg z = \pi/4$ and ended up with a circle centered at (1/2; -1/2) passing 0 and 1. However, I am not sure how these relate and how could you come up with those 3 points $0, i, \infty$?